# How can I make this run? (window.btoa)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, base64

This script extracts an Excel file from an HTML table:

http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/wVejP/

It runs perfectly fine in Chrome and other browsers, but not in IE9. My company still has IE9 as its standard browser so I have to make it compatible with that.  I'm aware hat it's because "window.btoa" is not yet supported in IE9, but a workaround is to use "base64.encode" instead.   I already added "base64.js" to my code and modified the code to:

```
base64Excel = function(s) {
    if (!window.btoa){
        //For IE9 that doesn't support window.btoa yet
        return base64.encode(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) 
    } else {
        return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
    }
}
```

Now I don't see any errors in the browser console, but nothing is happening at all when I click the Export button.  The modified script still works with Chrome and other.  Any ideas?

Comment: the encoding might work just fine, but you can't open a js-generated file in IE9 like in chrome.

Comment: I see. So probably at this point it's the opening of the js-generated file that's the issue.  Really no work around for that?

Comment: downloadify has a flash fallback (i think)... something like that is out there for sure (i've seen it)
, google "download file js" or something like that